# DrawRect not displaying shape?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to implement two subclasses at one time.

I am using the `UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>` subclass in my viewController to be able to work with the gps. While using `UIView` subclass to draw.

This is a summary of the code I have:

MapViewController.h:

```
@interface MapViewController: UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>{
DrawCircle *circleView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) DrawCircle *circleView;
@end
```

DrawCircle.h:

```
@interface DrawCircle : UIView
-(void)addPoint:(CGPoint)point;
@end
```

What I was trying to do here was to make DrawCircle a property of MapViewController. However I am still having no luck drawing anything to the screen.

Here is my DrawCircle.m code if it helps at all:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self) {
        _points = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)addPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    //Wrap the point in an NSValue to add it to the array
    [_points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
    //This will tell our view to redraw itself, calling drawRect
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    for(NSValue *pointValue in _points) {
        CGPoint point = [pointValue CGPointValue];
        CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(point.x - 10, point.y - 10, 20, 20));
    }

    CGContextSetFillColor(ctx, CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor redColor] CGColor]));
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
}
```

Also as a last bit of information I can give to you all. Here is a snapshot of my map view controller scene.
[image: MapViewController Scene]

I have a feeling that the shape is being drawn, but being covered up somehow.

**EDIT**
After further investigation, it appears that the shapes being drawn are being covered by my UIImage. I was just messing around and removed the UIImage, and my shapes were there. Now the question is, how do i "move to back" my UIImage, so that my shapes are up front?

Comment: Let me ask you this: do you know for a fact that DrawCircle *ever* draws successfully? In other words, can you guarantee that, outside the context of this particular app, its `drawRect` does work?

Comment: Yessir. I was just messing around, and it appears that my uiimage is actually covering up my shapes I am drawing. I deleted it, and my shape is appearing. Do you know how to move the image to the bottom layer so that the uiview is upfront.

Comment: Yes, I do: there are methods on UIView for changing the layering order, `bringSubviewToFront` and that sort of thing.

Comment: Also note that the order shown in your Interface Builder hierarchical outline *is* the layering order of the subviews.

Comment: Maybe the problem here is that the UIImageView is the subview of the wrong view. If it is a subview of your DrawCircle it will certainly be drawn in front of your DrawCircle!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I also have one more question for you. As you can see in my addPoint method, I am redrawing the shapes to the view by calling [self needsUpdateDisplay]. When debugging, this method is being called, but not redirecting me to my drawRect method. It is just leaving the class and continuing.

Comment: `drawRect` is called *later* (after your code finishes)

Comment: All drawing is performed after your code is done (I call this the "redraw moment" - effectively, it is idle time)

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside `drawRect` you will see that it *is* called eventually

Comment: Oh that makes complete sense. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @JohnnyWhisman i guess you need to bring your `CircleView` on top of hierarchy when you diaplay it, so write this code to bringInFront      [self.view bringSubviewToFront:circleView];